# count cells quantity with a special contained word and calculate the percentage

Tags: string, excel, count, percentage

How can I count cells quantity with a special contained word and calculate the percentage in excel?

For example I have a survey database about a product.
the feedbacks are "Good, Not Bad, Bad".

I want to count the quantity of each type of feedbacks and finally calculate the percentages and draw a diagram of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be achievable simply with `COUNTIF`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

[image]

Formulas:

`E1`

```
=SUM($E$2:$E$10000)
```

`E2` downwards as needed:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,$D2)
```

`F1` downwards as needed:

```
=$E1/$E$1
```